# auto search through highlighting in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Sometimes when I click the cursor in a variable or method it will highlight it and highlight all other occurrences.

I quite like this but it only seems to work when it wants to :(

How can i make it work manually so that it will always happen when given the chance instead of in just some source files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a button on your toolbar. It looks like a pen. Its tooltip is "Toggle mark occurrences" and the hot key is Alt-Shift-O.

Comment: That's working for some stuff but it still doesn't work for the variable I'm trying to track

Answer (score 2):

maybe you don´t have marked all types in settigns (Preferences > Java > Editor > Mark Occurrences...)